# Как изменить regexp

Tags: javascript

Доброй ночи, требуется из кода, который ищет id ютуба в ссылках картинок `let regexp = /https:\/\/i\.ytimg\.com\/vi\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/maxresdefault\.jpg/i;` сделать код, который бы искал по простой ссылке `https://youtu.be/KkcrQTqr9q4`.
Пишу вот так, но не работает `let regexp = /https:\/\/youtu\.be\/\([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/;`
Я далек от понимания этого скрипта, если есть возможность напишите сразу код, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

```
const reg = /https:\/\/youtu\.be\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/;
const href = 'https://youtu.be/KkcrQTqr9q4';
const result = href.match(reg);
const id = result?result[1]:result;
```

Comment: Евгений спасибо огромное! 
Я только понять не могу, почему код не работает?

function parseMediaURL(media) {
    let regexp = /https:\/\/youtu\.be\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/;
    let url = media.src;
    let match = url.match(regexp);

    return match[1];
}

Comment: видимо что то не то подаете в функцию.  И при return поставьте проверку на случай что регулярка не не нашла совпадение return match?match[1]:match; Тогда функция вернет undefined, а не вывалится с ошибкой

Comment: Спасибо! Всех благ Вам!